# Difference Between two UiDatePickers that populate two UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I need to get the difference (in days) between two `UIDatePicker` that are being stored in two `UITextField`.

I got this here in the forum, but it's not working.

```
1. let inicio = inicioTextField.text
2. let fim = fimTextField.text

3. let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
4. dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
5. let inicioDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inicio)
6. let fimDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fim)

7. let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
8. let unit = NSCalendarUnit.Day
9. let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: inicioDate, toDate: fimDate, options: [])
```

I'm receiving a message to add a ! after lines 5 and 6, but it's not working, the app crash before start.

In the future I will need to check this amount of days to set up lot of cases.

This is how my UITextFild is populated

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {

    let datePickerViewInicio: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerViewInicio.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

    sender.inputView = datePickerViewInicio

    datePickerViewInicio.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

    inicioTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
```

FULL CODE!

```
@IBOutlet weak var inicioTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var fimTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var motivoTextField: UITextField!

var motivos: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Toolbar para data de Início

    let motivoPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

    motivos = ["Pedido de demissão","Dispensa sem justa causa","Dispensa com justa causa", "Término do contrato de experiência"]

    motivoPicker.delegate = self
    motivoPicker.dataSource = self
    motivoTextField.inputView = motivoPicker

    let toolBarIni = UIToolbar()
    toolBarIni.sizeToFit()
    toolBarIni.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBarIni.tintColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 20/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)


    let hojeBtnIni = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Hoje", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "tappedToolBarBtn:")

    let okBarBtnIni = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "donePressed:")

    let flexSpaceIni = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    let labelInicio = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3, height: self.view.frame.size.height))

    labelInicio.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)

    labelInicio.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    labelInicio.textColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 20/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)

    labelInicio.text = "Início do contrato"

    labelInicio.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let textBtnIni = UIBarButtonItem(customView: labelInicio)

    toolBarIni.setItems([hojeBtnIni,flexSpaceIni,textBtnIni,flexSpaceIni,okBarBtnIni], animated: false)

    inicioTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBarIni

    //toolbar para data do Fim


    let toolBarFim = UIToolbar()

    toolBarFim.sizeToFit()
    toolBarFim.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBarFim.tintColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 20/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)


    let todayBtnFim = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Hoje", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "tappedToolBarBtnFim:")

    let okBarBtnFim = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "donePressedFim:")

    let flexSpaceFim = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    let labelFim = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3, height: self.view.frame.size.height))

    labelFim.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)

    labelFim.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    labelFim.textColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 20/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)

    labelFim.text = "Fim do contrato"

    labelFim.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let textBtnFim = UIBarButtonItem(customView: labelFim)

    toolBarFim.setItems([todayBtnFim,flexSpaceFim,textBtnFim,flexSpaceFim,okBarBtnFim], animated: true)

    fimTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBarFim

    //Toolbar para Motivo

    let toolBarMot = UIToolbar()
    toolBarMot.sizeToFit()
    toolBarMot.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBarMot.tintColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 20/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)


    //let hojeBtnMot = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancelar", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "tappedToolBarBtnMot:")

    let okBarBtnMot = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "donePressedMot:")

    let flexSpaceMot = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    let labelMot = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3, height: self.view.frame.size.height))

    labelMot.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 11)

    labelMot.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    labelMot.textColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 20/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)

    labelMot.text = "Motivo da demissão"

    labelMot.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

    let textBtnMot = UIBarButtonItem(customView: labelMot)

    toolBarMot.setItems([textBtnMot,flexSpaceMot,okBarBtnMot], animated: false)

    motivoTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBarMot

    let inicio = inicioTextField.text
    let fim = fimTextField.text



    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    let inicioDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inicio)
    let fimDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fim)

    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let unit = NSCalendarUnit.Day
    let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: inicioDate, toDate: fimDate, options: [])



}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//Ação dos botões da toolbar Início 

func donePressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    inicioTextField.resignFirstResponder()

}

func tappedToolBarBtn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    inicioTextField.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    inicioTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

//Ação dos botões da toolbar Fim

func donePressedFim(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    fimTextField.resignFirstResponder()

}

func tappedToolBarBtnFim(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    fimTextField.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    fimTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//Ação dos botões da toolbar Motivo

func donePressedMot(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    motivoTextField.resignFirstResponder()

}

//Associação de valor para TexField Início

@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {

    let datePickerViewInicio: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerViewInicio.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

    sender.inputView = datePickerViewInicio

    datePickerViewInicio.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

    inicioTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)


}

//Associação de valor para TexField Início

@IBAction func textFieldEditingFim(sender: UITextField) {

    let datePickerViewFim: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerViewFim.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

    sender.inputView = datePickerViewFim

    datePickerViewFim.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChangedFim:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}

func datePickerValueChangedFim(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatterFim = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatterFim.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    dateFormatterFim.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

    fimTextField.text = dateFormatterFim.stringFromDate(sender.date)

}

//Associação de valor para TexField Início

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return motivos.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    motivoTextField.text = motivos[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return motivos[row]
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63424.png)

I'm very new on this, so someone can help?

Thanks

Comment: can you print out `inicio` and `fim` after line 2 to see which format the dates have please?

Comment: @AndréSlotta how can I print it without change so much my code?

Comment: simply insert `print("inicio: \(inicio), fim: \(fim)")` between lines 2 and 3.

Comment: But, where can I check the result? Because I need to select the pickers inside both `UITextView` to generate the results, and after this I need to print what is there.

Comment: would you like to share your project or some of your code? makes it easier...

Comment: I add how the UITextField is populated.

Comment: so after `inicioTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)` add the print statement i wrote above...

Comment: Hi! Sorry on the delay, I went out to my house and only now reach my job again. It's not working this way.

Comment: then you maybe should share your project so that i can take a deeper look on what's going wrong...

Comment: update my post, check it.

Comment: best would be dropbox or something... but what is the problem at all? do you get any error messages or something?

Comment: Yes, it's asking to add a ! after lines 5 and 6, after do this, it's build successful, but when simulator open, it crashs.

Comment: xcode says to to this:

`let inicioDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inicio!)!`
`let fimDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fim!)!`

Comment: and when it crashes... what is the exception text?

Comment: simulator don't open, crash in the beggining, with message: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) and marks the line `let inicioDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inicio!)!`

Comment: that is why you need to `print` the value of `inicio` right before that line to see what it contains!

Comment: I put the a screen shot of error message in the post.

Comment: please add `print(inicio)` right before `let inicioDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inicio)` and show or tell what it prints out in the debug area!

Comment: I put it, but don't show nothing

Comment: can you answer how can I get this difference between two datepickers? IN this case, I'm using as inputview for a texfield.

Comment: i set up a quick demo project. hope it helps: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3cq3po4bdcx5hyj/AACfP9-j0EGjcrxTW6htSS3xa?dl=0

Comment: I understood your code and it's exactly what I need, but my datepicker is working as an inputview, and I don't have an IBOutlet for it. I really don't know what to do.. :s

Comment: And I also have a toolbar with an OK button.

Comment: check this: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3cq3po4bdcx5hyj/AACfP9-j0EGjcrxTW6htSS3xa?dl=0

Comment: That's awesome! Don't you wanna put something as answer, just to check at acceptable and earn 2 reputation points?

Comment: glad i could help. added an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
func daysBetween(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Int {
  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  let dateComponents = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: calendar.startOfDayForDate(startDate), toDate: calendar.startOfDayForDate(endDate), options: [])
  return dateComponents.day
}
```